# AT commands on esp8266 module

Tags: arduino, at-command, esp8266

Actually,the command AT+CWSAP? returns the values +CWSAP:ssid,pwd,ch,ecn OK
but i give this command to my esp8266 module its printing more two parameters rather then the actual parameters.can any one figure it out about the other two parameters.

+CWSAP:"AI-THINKER_074510","",1,0,4,0

Answer (score 0):

Response to CWSAP is as below:

**+CWSAP: "ssid", "pwd", "chl", "ecn", "maxconn", "ssidhidden"**

***ssid*** and ***pwd*** are your ESP's broadcast ssid and password.

***chl*** is the channel id.

***ecn*** is encryption method
0: OPEN
2: WPA_PSK
3: WPA2_PSK
4: WPA_WPA2_PSK

***maxconn*** defines maximum number of Stations to which ESP8266 SoftAP can be connected within the range of [1, 10]

***ssidhidden*** defines if the ssid is broadcasted 
0: Broadcasted
1: Hidden